# running a Python script for each line of a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

How can I perform the following task in bash?

I need to write a script that runs a python script on each line of a text file as an input separately and then saves the result in json file named after the line it reads the file from.

So text file 10tweets.txt looks like below:

cat 10tweets.txt

```
Trump on the other hand goes all in on water boarding AND some. #GOPDebate
RT @wpjenna Donald Trump promises that he will not touch the 2nd amendment -- "unless we're going to make it stronger."
Trump 23%, Rubio 19%, Kasich & Bush 14%, Christie 10%, Cruz 9% #NHPrimary
@realDonaldTrump Thank you for saying you won't use vulger language anymore. Talk about Sanders & Clinton. Take Cruz as VP. Mexican votes!!!
RT @SurfPHX Mr. Trump @realDonaldTrump tweeted 25 minutes ago. You all do realize, that our future President hardly sleeps. He's a Fighter and a Worker!
go, Bernie #DemDebate
Sanders calls out Clinton on taking Foreign Policy advice from Warmonger Henry Kissinger https://t.co/xT5J4uh4m4 via @YouTube
Cruz, Rubio, and the Moral Bankruptcy of Progressive Identity Politics https://t.co/kSQstJXtKO via @NRO
RT @scarylawyerguy "Who does Bernie Sanders listen to on foreign policy." - A question Hillary had to raise b/c the media will not. #DemDebate
Why Did U of California Fire Tenured Riverside Professor? / Ted Cruz and Higher Ed -- ... - https://t.co/zFxa4Q70wh
```

and I want the output be like 1.json, 2.json, 3.json, 4.json, 5.json in output folder.

Not sure how to make use of `exec entity_sentiment.py "$@"` in a bash script and link it to each line from the file.
The way the script is ran is like below

```
$ python entity_sentiment.py sentiment-entities-text "Thank you for saying you won't use vulger language anymore"
Mentions: 
Name: "vulger language"
  Begin Offset : 35
  Content : vulger language
  Magnitude : 0.699999988079071
  Sentiment : -0.699999988079071
  Type : 2
Salience: 1.0
Sentiment: magnitude: 0.699999988079071
score: -0.699999988079071
```

In which for example, the input to script could be assumed the first line of the file.

Basically, running the following bash script only analyzes the last line of the file and saves it in 1.json

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1

while read -u 3 -r line; do
  python entity_sentiment.py sentiment-entities-text "$line" > "$((n++)).json"
done 3< 10tweets.txt
```

Here's an snippet of what happens when I ran a suggest in bash IRC channel: https://pastebin.com/raw/VQpPFJYs and https://pastebin.com/raw/GQefrTX0

Comment: This is how the output of `echo $n ${line::30}` is supposed to look like: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/87kYs6fvpn/ What is the output of `/bin/bash --version`?

Answer (score 0):

You can `read` the input file line-by-line and apply a command to each line using something like

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1

while read -r line; do
  python entity_sentiment.py sentiment-entities-text "$line" > "$((n++)).json"
done < input.txt
```

I don't see how `exec entity_sentiment.py "$@"` would be helpful.

Comment: http://codepad.org/Iu6xV2jV didn't work. Only created one json file

Comment: @MonaJalal your question refers to a file `input.txt` but your linked `ls` output does not appear to include such a file - you will need to replace `input.txt` by the name of your **actual** file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/GQefrTX0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to IRC bash community

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1

while read -u 3 -r line; do
  echo $n "${line::30}"
  python entity_sentiment.py sentiment-entities-text "$line" > "$((n++)).json"
  ((n++))
done 3< 10tweets.txt
```